# Fill one column with information from another column using awk

Tags: awk

I have two files which separated by tabs：

file1.txt:

```
1 KD 
2 LBJ
3 YAO
4 LBJ
5 YAO
6 MJ
7 MJ
8 YAO
9 KD
```

file2.txt:

```
KD 35
LBJ 6
YAO 11
MJ  23
```

Expected output:

```
1 KD 35 
2 LBJ 6
3 YAO 11
4 LBJ 6
5 YAO 11
6 MJ 23
7 MJ 23
8 YAO 11
9 KD 35
```

Any help in awk is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it with awk:

```bash
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0, a[$2]}' file2 file1
1   KD  35  
2   LBJ 6
3   YAO 11
4   LBJ 6
5   YAO 11
6   MJ  23
7   MJ  23
8   YAO 11
9   KD  35
```

Another option is to use `join` command:

```bash
join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 2.2 -t $'\t' <(sort -k2,2 file1) <(sort file2) | sort -n
```

Explanation:

- `-1 2 -2 1` tells the `join` command to join the second field of the first with the first field of the second file
- `-o 1.1 1.2 2.2` This specifies the order of the fields in the output. The number before the dot is the file number, the number after the dot is the field number of the file
- `-t $'\t'` specifies that the delimiter is the tab character
- `<(sort -k2,2 file1) <(sort file2)` sorts the files by the field to be joined. The `join` command requires that the files are sorted.
- `| sort -n` sorts the output file

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, I'll keep that in mind.